# How to space cols in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment, col

Im having trouble with a college project and I cant quite get my head around it. From what I have read online you use the col-xx-x to space divs along the 12 column grid. I am trying that here to get both input boxes centered along the upper row with the outside edge of the buttons aligned on the row below with outside edge of the input boxes above.

Im not sure if this is something I should fix with CSS or with the col-md-x. Thanks for any help :-)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>        <!-- spacing divs-->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>        <!-- spacing divs-->
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>    <!-- spacing divs-->
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Reset Psasword</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>    <!-- spacing divs-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put empty div's using col-xx-x thing. Instead, if You want empty columns use col-xx-offset-x.

Read more here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting